# How to give foreign key name in django

Tags: python, django

I built a model called bbs with a reference to User table.

```
class Bbs_User(models.Model):
    sid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    #...

class Bbs(models.Model):
    sid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    writer  = models.ForeignKey(Bbs_User)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    content = models.TextField()

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'Bbs'

    def __str__(self)
        return self.title
```

In mysql client, I have look into Bbs table layout.

```
mysql> desc Bbs
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+ 
| sid         | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| writer_id   | int(11)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
```

At this point, I want to know why the field name is 'writer_id'.
I think the field name must be 'writer_sid' or 'writer'.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 22):

By default, Django populates column's name by appending `_id` to the field name you define in your model. You must explicitly specify column's name using  [`db_column`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#db-column) property as follows:

```
writer = models.ForeignKey(Bbs_User, db_column='writer_sid')
```

Answer (score 11):

Foreign Keys are automatically named that way by the framework, but you can change the name of the column using `db_column` parameter when declaring the field:

```
myKey = models.ForeignKey('MyRelatedModel', db_column='my_column_name')
```

**Update:** I should mention that the automatic naming has some advantages when making queries: if you call `myBbsInstance.writer.id` you would get a RelatedManager instance that you need to resolve, hitting the database, to just getting the id, while calling `myBbsInstance.writer_id` just return the number inserted in the column, without a database hit. It's very mnemonic.